# Does wifi enables wifi-direct too

Tags: android, android-wifi, multiplayer, wifi-direct, wifip2p

Does switching on `wifi` enables `wifi-direct` too?

If yes Then what is the need of this intent **`Wifip2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`**?

If no Then how to enable or disable **`WIFI-DIRECT`**?Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is the reasoning you have for the requirement of disabling the Wifi Direct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes when you trun on your wifi **Wifi-Direct** facility also enables 
have a look at the below link for reference there you can get how you can play with this facility.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

and if you want to check wether your wifi is on or of write below code

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
//wifi is enabled
}
```

also for details have a look at the below link it contain code for what you need just import it and run it.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo

Comment: Yeah Farooq.Thanks for that but I am not clear about this- intent "Wifip2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION" will be broadcasted  when wifip2p changes(ON/OFF). If it does not change then how to check status of wifip2p??

Answer (score 0):

Basically the Wifip2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION events will follow when you turn Wifi on or Off.

I suppose if there would be any other internal conditions which are required by the API itself, then you would get these events also for any other changes (I'm not aware of any at this point of time though)

My observation has been that when you register the event listener it appears to fire the event strait away, thus you could get it during the creation time of your class instance.

Anyway, I have not seen any ways on disabling the Wifi Direct from the API, though its rather badly behaving API implementation, thus it can be used in a way that disables other usages, though I would not recommend using it that way.